# MKMapView doesn't show current location

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, mkmapview

I'm trying to get an MKMapView show my current location. I managed to get this working in an application with a single view, but now I'm trying to implement the same view inside a UITabBarController. My code is more or less the same, but I still can't get it to work.

I'm following the BigNerdRanch guide on iPhone development. I implemented the view like they did with the other views in the book; I first wrote the `init` method:

```
#import "CurrentLocationViewController.h"
#import "MapPoint.h"

@implementation CurrentLocationViewController

    - (id)init
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:@"CurrentLocationViewController"
                               bundle:nil];
        if (self) {
            UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];
            [tbi setTitle:@"Location"];

            UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Hypno.png"];
            [tbi setImage:i];

            locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            [locationManager setDelegate:self];
            [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
            [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];

            [worldView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

        }

        return self;
    }
```

And I made that init method the designated initializer by doing this aswell:

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    return [self init];
}
```

As you can see, I did call `setShowsUserLocation:YES` on my `worldview` which is declared as: `IBOutlet MKMapView *worldView;` in my header file.

I'm probably missing something here, but I thought that message was the only thing I needed to get the **basic** mapview working? Any ideas?

I can provide more code if necessary. The view does load properly btw, I checked with an obnoxious colour first and it does show the map. It just doesn't put a blue pin on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created the MapView in a xib file, have you made sure that you have connected the worldView outlet?

Also, you don't need to set up CoreLocation for this. Just for comparison - here's my controller definition for the same exercise. It doesn't show - but I set the shows user location property in the xib file rather than in code.

```
#import "MapViewController.h"

@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize mapView;

// New designated initialiser
-(id)init {
    if (!(self = [super initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil])) {
        return nil; // Bail!
    }
    UITabBarItem *tbi = self.tabBarItem;
    tbi.title = @"Map";
    tbi.image = nil;

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    return [self init];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [mapView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setMapView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - MapKit delegate methods

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation.location coordinate];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 1000.0f, 1000.0f);
    [aMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried with your code now but I couldn't get it to work either. I then figured I needed to make it start looking somewhere, but perhaps not in init, so I implemented `viewDidLoad`: `- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [worldView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}` and now it works :D. I guess this is what you did in the xib, and I did it programmatically?

Comment: One more thing though. I set up CoreLocation because that's what they did in chapter 6. Is MKMapView capable of looking for the location on it's own then? I wasn't sure if I should or shouldn't set up CoreLocation, but I did so to be sure.

Comment: Yep - as you can see with my controller - I don't use CL. I don't even have the framework in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing in Simulator only? The blue userLocation dot in Simulator is displayed at 1 Infinite Loop, which means you may not be able to see it if you are zoomed in on a region that does not display Cupertino.

Comment: No, I was testing both on device and in simulator. I know about 1 Infinite Loop. I just forgot to implement `viewDidLoad`. Thanks for the advice though!